# this["var"+"name"] in java

Tags: java, actionscript-3

In AS3 I can write `this["foo"]` for access to a variable `foo`. I can construct any string in brackets. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? In other words: where does the string 'foo' come from? Is it a user input or is it in some way hardcoded?

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language, If you are trying to go against the basic premises for the lingo, you are using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java's reflection API to achieve the same effect, albeit much less elegantly. See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) for a tutorial.

Comment: Not to mention slower and potentially insecure.

Comment: Slower than ActionScript's this["foo"]? Perhaps, but I'd say there's sufficient uncertainty to warrant measuring the difference.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.  But you don't need to.  There's an easier way to call variables.  You just need to use this.foo to refer to the variable.  Now, if you're trying to do something like

```
String var = "foo";
this[var] = "something else";
```

You may be able to do that with java reflection, but it would have quite a bit of overhead and I believe it would be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want such kind of access, you should consider using Set interface (or reflection api, as noted before me).